# Why isn't the if else structure working in c++?

Tags: c++, if-statement

I have been trying to write tictactoe in c++ but I don't know why the if else statements aren't getting executed.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

char XorO;

int n;

char a = '1';
char b = '2';
char c = '3';
char d = '4';
char e = '5';
char f = '6';
char g = '7';
char h = '8';
char i = '9';

int charchange[] = {79, 80, 81, 575, 6786, 75, 7879, 67697, 689698};
void Welcome() // FUNCTION1
{
    cout << "\nWelcome to Tic-Tac-toe!!!\n";
    cout << "You are going to play with the computer!!\n";
    cout << "Press X to choose X or press O to choose O for the game!!: ";
}

void framework() //FUNCTION2
{
    cout << " _ _ _ " << endl;
    cout << "| | | |" << endl;
    cout << "|"<< a <<"|"<< b <<"|"<< c <<"|" << endl;
    cout << "|"<< d <<"|"<< e <<"|"<< f <<"|" << endl;
    cout << "|"<< g <<"|"<< h <<"|"<< i <<"|" << endl;
    cout << "|_|_|_|" << endl;
}

int main()
{
    aiyeee:
    Welcome();
    cin >> XorO;  ////////////GETS EXCECUTED TILL HERE
    if (XorO == 'X')          ////////////////////////DSEN'T EXECUTE
    {
        for(n=1;n>=9;n++)
     {
        if(n%2 != 0){
        framework();
        cout << "\nOk:)";
        aeneas:
        cout << " Your turn!! Which number to change to X: ";
        cin >> charchange[(n-1)];
        for (int ty = 1; ty <= 9; ty++)
        {
            if(charchange[(n-1)] != ty)
            {
                cout << "INVALID INPUT!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
        }
        switch(charchange[(n-1)])
        {
            case 1:
            if (a == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            a = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 2:
            if (b == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            b = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 3:
            if (c == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            c = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 4:
            if (d == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to O!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            d = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 5:
            if (e == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            e = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 6:
            if (f == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            f = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 7:
            if (g == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            g = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 8:
            if (h == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            h = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
            case 9:
            if (i == 'O')
            {
                cout << "\nAlready Changed to 'O'!!\n";
                goto aeneas;
            }
            i = 'X';
            framework();
            break;
        }
        if(n>4)
        {
            if ((a==b && b==c)||(d==e && e==f)||(g==h && h==i)||(a==d && d==g)||(b==e && g==h)||(c==f && f==i)||(a==e && e==i)||(c==e && e==f))
            {                   
                cout << "YOU WIN!!!\n";
                goto allagulla;
            }
        }
        }

        else if(n%2 == 0)
        {
            aghhg:
            charchange[n-1] = ((rand()%9) + 1);
            switch (charchange[n-1])
            {
                case 1:
                if(a == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                a = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 2:
                if(b == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                b = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 3:
                if(c == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                c = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 4:
                if(d == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                d = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 5:
                if(e == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                e = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 6:
                if(f == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                f = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 7:
                if(g == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                g = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 8:
                if(h == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                h = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
                case 9:
                if(i == 'X') 
                    {
                        goto aghhg;
                    }
                i = 'O';
                framework();
                break;
            }
            if(n>4)
        {
            if ((a==b && b==c)||(d==e && e==f)||(g==h && h==i)||(a==d && d==g)||(b==e && g==h)||(c==f && f==i)||(a==e && e==i)||(c==e && e==f))
            {                   
                cout << "COMPUTER WINS!!\n";
                break;
            }
        }
        }
    }
    }
    else if (XorO == 'O')
    {

    }

    else
    {
        cout << "\nINVALID INPUT!!!\n";
        goto aiyeee;
        cin >> XorO;    
    }

    allagulla:
    cout << "\nWanna play again?(y/n) ";/////////////////////COMES DOWN STRAIGHT HERE AFTER THE PREV COMM
    char yesno;
    yesno = getche();
    if (yesno == 'y')
        {
            goto aiyeee;
        }
    }
```

After main() starts it inputs the XorO but then it comes down to Wanna play again? Seriously I dunno why:(     Sorry for the long program maybe it could have been shorter actually I am learning c++.

Comment: Could you add some print statements in the code which show which statements are not giving you the results you expect? Also, is it possible for you to only include enough code which illustrates your issue?

Comment: Maybe stupid, but did you hit Enter after 'x' or 'o'?

Comment: It would help a lot if you indented your code properly.  I don't know how you (or anyone else) can follow it with it laid out like it is.

Comment: "Sorry for the long program" Don't do this. Write **much** less at a time and **make sure it works** before you let yourself do **even a little bit** more. In the long run, you will be thankful.

Comment: screenshot of your execution terminal willl help

Comment: Your for loop is incorrect `for(n=1;n>=9;n++)` should be `for(n=1;n<=9;n++)`. Which means that you wrote all that code without testing it **once**. Seriously that is not a good way to write code. No professional would work in that way. Write a little bit of code, test it, make sure it's working (as far as it goes), then write a little bit more code. That's how professionals work, because they understand it's impossible to write correct code without testing it **as you write it**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Learn how to use a debugger

Compile with `-g`:

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic -g -o demo demo.cpp
```

Run the debugger:

```
gdb demo
```

Put a breakpoint in the suspicious line:

```
(gdb) break 44
Punto de interrupción 1 at 0x1502: file demo.cpp, line 44.
(gdb) run
```

Ask the debugger:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at demo.cpp:44
44      if (XorO == 'X')          ////////////////////////DSEN'T EXECUTE
(gdb) print XorO
$1 = 88 'X'
(gdb) step
46          for(n=1;n>=9;n++)
(gdb) step
259     cout << "\nWanna play again?(y/n) ";/////////////////////COMES DOWN STRAIGHT HERE AFTER THE PREV COMM
(gdb) print n
$2 = 1
(gdb)
```

Do you see? `n` is never greater or equal than 9, thus is jumping the whole `for` loop.

On the other hand, try to simplify the task for those who review your code, most of us do not have the `conio` libraries and I have had to replace `getche` with `getc(stdin)`, by the way `getche` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

```
char yesno;
```

should be

```
int yesno;
```